# Keyframes animation on hover: Skipping initial regular state animation

Tags: css, animation, hover, keyframe

I have an overlay effect I am trying to achieve where a text block overlays on top of an image when hovered.

I had a basic version with transitions working, but I wanted to add a little bounce to the scaling, so I created in and out keyframes animations.

When I apply the two animations to the regular and hover states, and everything works as expected. However, I want to skip the regular state animation on initial load so you don't see the overlay exiting on load. Is there any way to do this without JavaScript?

Here is a Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJjNrg

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-6.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="overlay">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet rerum in illum earum a, possimus, eum aliquam quia. Inventore, repudiandae fuga. Ducimus porro illo eum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dicta.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.overlay{
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translateY(120%) scale(0);
  animation: fadeScaleBounceOut 1s;
}

.box:hover .overlay{
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
  animation: fadeScaleBounceIn 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeScaleBounceIn{
  0%{
    transform: translateY(120%) scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scale(1.1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeScaleBounceOut{
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scale(1.1);  
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(120%) scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to stay with transitions. You can get them to be quite sophisticated.

Here is my attempt to get your effect using them, instead of keyframes. I am using cubic bezier to get the bounce effect on the scale()

```css
.box{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.overlay{
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .7);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc( 100% - 60px );
  top: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-property: top, opacity, transform;
  transition-duration: 0.8s, 0.8s, 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.43, 1.5);
}

.box:hover .overlay{
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-6.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="overlay">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet rerum in illum earum a, possimus, eum aliquam quia. Inventore, repudiandae fuga. Ducimus porro illo eum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dicta.
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, if you are using Chrome, you can edit the bezier curve live

[image: screen shot]